# build/deploy script in product repo or in external repo?

Tags: python, configuration, jenkins, automation, fabric

I am working on a web project written in python. Here are some facts:

- Project hosted on GitHub
- [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (a python library for build and deploy automation) script (`fabfile.py`) for automatic build and deploy
- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for build automation

My question is, where to put the `fabfile.py` conventionally.

I prefer to put the `fabfile.py` in the root of the project repo so that I can config jenkins job to grab the source code from git and simply run `fab build` to get the compiled package.

Someone insists that the `fabfile.py` should NOT be part of the project repo, it should be kept in an external repo instead. In this case you need to config jenkins to clone the fabfile repo, invoke git to clone the product repo then run packaging.

I know this is probably a matter of personal flavor, but are there any benefits to put `fabfile.py` in a separate repo than to put it with the product code?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I cant see being no right or wrong answer for this. I would personally put it with project repo.

Comment: @smushi Thanks for your comment! That is also what I am thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I can't see any benefits besides maybe preventing some junior dev accidentally deploying some unwanted code.

On the other hand, it's nice to have everything in one repo so you don't have to maintain multiple repositories.  In past experiences, we always included deployment scripts in the root of the project.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. I also believe it a good choice to put the scripts in the project.